# HTML form Submit button event is not triggered on the web server, but works in sandbox

Tags: html

I'm a bit of a HTML noobie but for some strange reason, my HTML form's Submit button event does not fire once it's uploaded to my web server but the same code works on my own computer.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` doesn't seem right.

Comment: So you want us to help you send spam?

Comment: It's for a diabetes event helping marketers. Thanks for your concern though.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript file doesn't seem to load. That might be the problem.

Change your js include to this url:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Not this: Which is wrong
../../../ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

This would be the problem:

http://listexplosionevents.com/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

You're trying to include jQuery from there.  I think it should just be `//ajax...`

You can see the error when you try to submit the form:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

This indicates that jQuery is not being included.  You also get.

> GET http://listexplosionevents.com/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Pay attention to the console!